# Connecting to Mysql from Mvc application using Entityframework

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using visual studio 2015 and created a Mvc application which I will like to connect to MySql database. I am able to connect to Mysql and my test connection turns out to be a success. However once I try to use entityframework I get the error message below.

I have tried a lot of things I found online but no luck for me. What am I doing wrong? Any documentation will be helpful

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to install mysql entity framework library to connect db through EF

install mysql entity framework from nuget

```
 Install-Package EntityFramework
 Install-Package MySql.Data.Entity -Version 6.10.4
```

if your using web application need to install

```
Install-Package MySql.Web -Version 6.10.4
```

In some cases you need to change little bit more in webconfig also

update providers to

```
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
</providers>
```

in connection string need to change provider  as

```
 providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
```

and in some case if you get exception like 'System.Data.StrongTypingException: The value for column 'IsPrimaryKey' in table. so you need to follow the steps given below

1. Open Services (services.msc) and restart MySQL57 service.
2. Execute the following commands in MySQL.
   use <>;
   set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=OFF';
3. Update the .edmx.